# Drag&Drop Image and CSS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have some objects created with CSS and some images load from the file. Drag&Drop is working for the CSS objects. But with the images, I have a problem. Start Drag and move is working. But if I release the mouse button the image is moving as long as the mouse movement until I press the button a second time. Then the image is placed at the point of the second click.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

```js
  var container = document.querySelector("#container");
      var activeItem = null;

      var active = false;

      container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
      container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
      container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

      container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
      container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
      container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

      function dragStart(e) {
        sAktClick = event.target.id;
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
          active = true;
          activeItem = e.target;

          if (activeItem !== null) {
            if (!activeItem.xOffset) {
              activeItem.xOffset = 0;
            }

            if (!activeItem.yOffset) {
              activeItem.yOffset = 0;
            }

            if (e.type === "touchstart") {
              activeItem.initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
              activeItem.initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
            } else {
              activeItem.initialX = e.clientX - activeItem.xOffset;
              activeItem.initialY = e.clientY - activeItem.yOffset;
            }
            var rec = document.getElementById(sAktNodeId).getBoundingClientRect();
            iDragStartX = rec.left;
            iDragStartY = rec.top;
          }
        }
      }

      function dragEnd(e) {
        if (event.target.id == "DemoCanvas") {
          return;
        }
        if (activeItem !== null) {
          activeItem.initialX = activeItem.currentX;
          activeItem.initialY = activeItem.currentY;
        }

      active = false;
      activeItem = null;

    Draw();
    ResizeSelect(sKreisBis, "kreisZu")
    ResizeSelect(sKreisVon, "kreisVon")
    ReposTextFields();
    bMoveAllowed = true;
      }

      function drag(e) {
        if (active) {
          if (e.type === "touchmove") {
            e.preventDefault();

            activeItem.currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - activeItem.initialX;
            activeItem.currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - activeItem.initialY;
          } else {
            activeItem.currentX = e.clientX - activeItem.initialX;
            activeItem.currentY = e.clientY - activeItem.initialY;
          }

          activeItem.xOffset = activeItem.currentX;
          activeItem.yOffset = activeItem.currentY;

          setTranslate(activeItem.currentX, activeItem.currentY, activeItem);
        }
      }

      function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
        el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
      }
```

```css
 .Mann {
      position: absolute;
      resize: both;
      top: 100px;
      left: 200px;
    }
        .kreis {
          float: left;
          position: absolute;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          border: 3px solid #037CA9;
          background-color: white;
          resize: both;
          top: 100px;
          left: 20px;
          z-index: 1002;
        }
```

```html
<img id="Mann1" src="bilder/User1_48.bmp" class="Mann">

<div class="item kreis" id="Kreis1" onclick="go(this);"></div>
```